# Plotly Animation Code not Plotting or playing

Tags: python, animation, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I have googled around a lot as well as have tried this code in both Jupiter Notebooks and Google Colab with no success.

Essentially I have 100 or so datafiles across a couple thousand wavelengths (in increments of 10) that I am trying to get the derivative to animate on the y axis to compare potential features in distinct groups (Though the application isn't really important).

If this wasn't an animation the data would best be displayed by 3 box and whisker plots. I set this up as a plotly scatter plot animation with each group getting a number on the x axis (1, 2, or 3) to fix them, and the varying derivatives should plot on the Y and change with the wavelength. My best guess is the error is in how I set up  my DataFrame, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to do it.

```
DataFrame ("SlopeInteractive"):

Wavelength  Type    X   Value
bir1jb740   1850    3   Y   -0.00001
bir1bu017   1850    3   Y   0.00002
bir1bu039   1850    3   Y   0.00001
bir1bu040   1850    3   Y   -0.00005
bir1wf015   1850    3   Y   0.00002
... ... ... ... ...
bir1jbg69a  8000    1   S   -0.00017
maze10  8000    2   T   -0.00146
maze57  8000    1   S   0.00041
maze15  8000    1   S   -0.00069
maze16  8000    1   S   -0.00078
108416 rows × 4 columns
```

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly

fig = go.Figure()

px.scatter(SlopeInteractive, x = "Type", y = "Value", color = "X", animation_frame = "Wavelength", animation_group="Type", hover_name = SlopeInteractive.index, category_orders = {"Wavelength" : wavelengthList})


fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 200, "redraw": False}} ])])],
            title = "Animation of groups Derivative change from 1850-8000nm", 
            xaxis_title = "SHOULDERS                 Doublets                 NONSHOULDER SINGLETS", 
            yaxis_title = "Derivative values at X wavelength")


frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 4], y=[1, 4])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[3, 4], y=[3, 4])],
                     layout=go.Layout(title_text="End Title"))]

fig.show()
```

.........

output:

It takes about 10seconds to run and outputs a blank graph with only the title and axis labels. The auto labels don't even make sense given the data set which makes me think it has no idea how to read my input.

......

I would greatly appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just forgot the fig = before the px. The proper block of code is

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig = px.scatter(SlopeInteractive, x = SlopeInteractive["Type"], y = SlopeInteractive["Value"], color = "X", animation_frame = SlopeInteractive["Wavelength"], animation_group="Value", hover_name = SlopeInteractive.index, category_orders = {"Wavelength" : wavelengthList}, range_y = [-0.02477, 0.0139])


fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 200, "redraw": False}} ])])],
            title = "Animation of groups Derivative change from 1850-8000nm", 
            xaxis_title = "SHOULDERS                 Doublets                 NONSHOULDER SINGLETS", 
            yaxis_title = "Derivative values at X wavelength")


frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 4], y=[1, 4])]),
            go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[3, 4], y=[3, 4])],
                     layout=go.Layout(title_text="End Title"))]

fig.show()
```

Note it works properly in both google colab and Jupiter notebooks.